# Strange error in Java

Tags: java, jar, compilation, classpath, javac

Can anyone tell why this error because if you put your work in the terminal? Here's the code.

I use this code to compile all files in a folder.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Compiles {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            List<String> compileFileCommand = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> files = new FileList().getListFile();
            List<String> libs = new ListLib().getListFile();
            compileFileCommand.add("/opt/java/bin/javac");

            for(int i = 0; i < files.size(); i++)
            {

                if(files.get(i).equals("Compiles.java"))
                    continue;

                if(files.get(i).equals("Compile.java"))
                    continue;

                String fileJar = new CreateFolder().currentData() + "/" + files.get(i) + " -cp lib/";

   //                       for (int y = 0; y < libs.size(); y++)
   //                       {
  //                            fileJar += libs.get(y) + ":";
  //                            if(libs.size() -1 == y)
  //                                fileJar += libs.get(y);  
  //                        }

                    fileJar += libs.get(0);



                    compileFileCommand.add(fileJar);

                    Process compile_process;
                    try {
                            compile_process = new ProcessBuilder(compileFileCommand)
                                            .redirectErrorStream(true).start();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            return;
                    }
                    try {
                            compile_process.waitFor();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                    compile_process.getInputStream()));
                    String line = null;
                    try {
                            line = reader.readLine();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    while (line != null) {
                            System.out.println(line);
                            try {
                                    line = reader.readLine();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                    }
            }
    }
}
```

The error is as follows

```
javac: invalid flag: temp_11.07.2012/CreateFolder.java -cp lib/gdata-media-1.0.jar
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

These are examples of data and this is what gives

Comment: What commandline do you use for compilation

Comment: No, what is the exact commandline being generated by your program.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to put the '-cp' options before the name of the file you want to compile ?

If it's not that, gives us the complete command line.

Comment: I tried it and '-cp' to put it anywhere and still did not work

Comment: The complete command line plz.

Comment: This ? 

javac: invalid flag: temp_11.07.2012/ -cp CreateFolder.java lib/gdata-media-1.0.jar
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options

Comment: I apologize for what many just want to give?

Comment: what do you type to obtain this error (this is what we want since the beginning), the complete javac call something like "javac -cp MyJar.jar MyClass.java"